# Counting number of occurrence of a specific string using Magento collection?

Tags: magento

I have mapped my custom table with Magento, so that i can fetch all data in it using below

```
 Mage::getModel('custom/filter')->getCollection();
```

Below is the sample table i have mapped

```
 
filter_id filters
------------------
1         5,6,5
3         77,8,5,77
10        22,55,33
```

I need to count the number of occurence of a specific string under field filters in this table using collection.

say for example, if i want to count occurence of 77 in 2nd row (filter_id = 3).
How do i do it with model collection?

I know i can use query to directly query the database using query methods in magento, but i am trying to do this in collection way.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks,

Balan

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding this correctly, the way that I would go about it would be to put your logic into the model. Simply put, you will make your selection like so:

```
$filter_id = 3;
$query = 77;

$collection = Mage::getModel('custom/filter')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('filter_id', $filter_id); // Hopefully it will be more than just one

foreach($collection as $filterModel) {

    $filterModel->getOccurrences($query);

}


/////******     Company/Custom/Model/Filter.php    ******////////


<?php
class Company_Custom_Model_Filter extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('custom/filter');
    }

    public function getOccurrences ($value)
    {
        $exploded = explode(',', $this->getFilters());
        $count = 0;

        foreach($exploded as $explodedValue) {
            if ($explodedValue === $value) $count++;
        }

        return $count;
    }

}
```

And, if you wanted to refactor this code into a collection, it will be pretty much the same iterator, going through each model. It is just a matter of where the initial code is called from.